# In 1 John 2:27, what is the meaning of the phrase "τὸ χρίσμα"?

Tags: greek, 1-john

In 1 John 2:27, it is written,

> <sup>27</sup> But **the anointing** which ye have received of him abideth in you, and ye need not that any man teach you: but as **the same anointing** teacheth you of all things, and is truth, and is no lie, and even as it hath taught you, ye shall abide in him. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>
>
> <sup>ΚΖʹ</sup> καὶ ὑμεῖς **τὸ χρίσμα** ὃ ἐλάβετε ἀπ᾽ αὐτοῦ, ἐν ὑμῖν μένει, καὶ οὐ χρείαν ἔχετε ἵνα τὶς διδάσκῃ ὑμᾶς ἀλλ᾽ ὡς **τὸ αὐτὸ χρίσμα** διδάσκει ὑμᾶς περὶ πάντων, καὶ ἀληθές ἐστιν, καὶ οὐκ ἔστιν ψεῦδος Καὶ καθὼς ἐδίδαξεν ὑμᾶς, μενεῖτε ἐν αὐτῷ <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

What is the meaning of the phrase "τὸ χρίσμα"? Does it refer to the Holy Spirit (as though "τὸ χρίσμα" is a circumlocution for "τὸ ἅγιον πνεῦμα"), or does it refer to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 27 But the anointing which you have **received from Him abides in you**, and you do not need that anyone teach you; but as the same anointing **teaches you concerning all things**, and **is true**, and is not a lie, and just as it has taught you, you will abide in Him. [(NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+john+2%3A27&version=NKJV)

The annointing refers to the Holy Spirit since it 1) was received from Jesus, 2) teaches you all things and 3) is true. These are references to [John 16:5-15 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+16&version=NKJV) (**emphasis above & below mine**):

> 5 “But now I [Jesus] go away to Him [the Father] who sent Me, and none of you asks Me, ‘Where are You going?’ 6 But because I have said these things to you, sorrow has filled your heart. 7 Nevertheless I tell you the truth. It is to your advantage that I go away; for if I do not go away, the Helper will not come to you; but if I depart, **I will send Him to you**. 8 And when He has come, He will convict the world of sin, and of righteousness, and of judgment: 9 of sin, because they do not believe in Me; 10 of righteousness, because I go to My Father and you see Me no more; 11 of judgment, because the ruler of this world is judged.
>
> 12 “I still have many things to say to you, but you cannot bear *them* now. 13 However, **when He, the Spirit of truth**, has come, **He will guide you into all truth**; for He will not speak on His own *authority*, but whatever He hears He will speak; and He will tell you things to come. 14 He will glorify Me, for He will take of what is Mine and declare *it* to you. 15 All things that the Father has are Mine. Therefore I said that He will take of Mine and declare *it* to you.

The anointing that was "received" and "abides in you" is later pointed out specifically to be the Spirit in [1 John 3:24 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+John+3&version=NKJV):

> 24 Now he who keeps His commandments abides in Him, and He in him. And by this we know that He abides in us, by the Spirit whom He has given us.

God abides in you and teaches you via the Holy Spirit, the Spirit of truth.

Answer (score 0):

In this verse the phrase "the anointing" is not merely refering to the Holy Spirit, but is rather refering to the ministry of the Holy Spirit. The ministry of the Holy Spirit is seen in John 15:1-5 as well as John 16:5-15. The Holy Spirit causes the life of Jesus "the vine" to flow into the branches and produce fruit. We as the branches simply spend time with Jesus "the Word of God" and the Holy Spirit gives us revelation knowledge of the Word. This is how we grow spiritually. This is how we experience the truth not just know it as information in our mind. Please share this message. Be blessed in Jesus name!

Comment: Hi Efrain! Welcome to Hermeneutics.SE. You might take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not already to get an idea of what constitutes a thorough answer. Can you show *from the text* how this refers to the Holy Spirit?